# weblogic managed server autostart

Tags: weblogic11g

Friends
I have configured WebLogic cluster with 2 managed servers and set crashrecoveryenabled to 'true' in nodemanager.properties so that in case of server crash the managed servers can start automatically.The Node manager and admin server are setup as windows services so that they can start automatically on server reboot. I have 2 questions
1.How can I make sure that the managed servers will start automatically after server reboot(I know adding managed servers as windows service is one option).
2.In nodemanager.properties do I need to set startscriptenabled to true in production environments?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I always set startScriptEnabled=true in production environments.  This just uses the script to start up the managed servers.

Provided crashRecoveryEnabled is set to true and you have started each of your managed servers then it will start.

You can use wlst to check if they are running (or start them) through some sort of scheduled task if you wish.

EDIT:  From the Oracle Documentation [4.2.4 Configuring Node Manager to Start Managed Servers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/core.1111/e10105/start.htm#ASADM11015)

If a Managed Server contains other Oracle Fusion Middleware products, such as Oracle SOA Suite, Oracle WebCenter Portal, or Oracle JRF, the Managed Servers environment must be configured to set the correct classpath and parameters. This environment information is provided through the start scripts, such as startWebLogic and setDomainEnv, which are located in the domain directory.

If the Managed Servers are started by Node Manager (as is the case when the servers are started by the Oracle WebLogic Server Administration Console or Fusion Middleware Control), Node Manager must be instructed to use these start scripts so that the server environments are correctly configured. Specifically, Node Manager must be started with the property StartScriptEnabled=true.

There are several ways to ensure that Node Manager starts with this property enabled. As a convenience, Oracle Fusion Middleware provides the following script, which adds the property **StartScriptEnabled=true** to the **nodemanager.properties** file:

(UNIX) ORACLE_COMMON_HOME/common/bin/setNMProps.sh.
(Windows) ORACLE_COMMON_HOME\common\bin\setNMProps.cmd
For example, on Linux, execute the setNMProps script and start Node Manager:

ORACLE_COMMON_HOME/common/bin/setNMProps.sh
MW_HOME/wlserver_n/server/bin/startNodeManager.sh
When you start Node Manager, it reads the nodemanager.properties file with the StartScriptEnabled=true property, and uses the start scripts when it subsequently starts Managed Servers. Note that you need to run the setNMProps script only once.

Comment: where do I need to go to set startScriptEnabled to true?

Comment: @Erick You can set `StartScriptEnabled=true` in `nodemanager.properties` which can be found in the path `[WLS Home goes here]\wlserver_10.3\common\nodemanager`

Comment: Make **sure** you change `StartScriptEnabled` and not `__Stop__ScriptEnabled`

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a service to have the managed servers start on system reboot is the preferred approach.

Comment: Hello. Would you please guide me through the process of creating it as a service?

Comment: You can find it in the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/web.1111/e13708/winservice.htm